# Setting OperatorSubstitution to false causes Plot's labels of sufficiently small size not to appear in the specified typeface. Is this a bug?

Tags: plotting, formatting, fonts

**This problem is no longer there after I upgraded to Mathematica 10.0.2.**

---

If I set `OperatorSubstitution` to `False`, the labels of `Plot` will not use the typeface specified by `FontFamily` unless `FontSize` is more than certain number.

In this test scenario, that certain number is `14` and the typeface is `Ubuntu` (Regular) (TTF fonts available from [font.ubuntu.com](http://font.ubuntu.com/)).

```
SetOptions[Plot, AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> {200, 200}]; 
Row[{
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Ubuntu", FontSize -> 14}, 
    BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> True}}], 
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Ubuntu", FontSize -> 14}, 
    BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}}], 
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, 
    LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Ubuntu", FontSize -> 15}, 
    BaseStyle -> {PrivateFontOptions -> {"OperatorSubstitution" -> False}}]
}]
```

[image: 15 is the threshold.]

Only some typefaces are affected (eg Inconsolata is fine). Is this a bug?

I'm using Mathematica 9 for Mac.